# MS Excel program

Tags: excel

I am creating a invoice in **Excel**.

I want to to get the total to be calculated from dropdown.

That means if I select **tax** inclusive it should show total amount as subtotal amount
and if i select exclusive it should calculate..

The amount I want the function to be applied to the dropdown how is it possible,,
img url below

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-act7lJiprYo/UBUdEKFtroI/AAAAAAAAAEc/r_j3lCzbvxA/s800/snap.png

thanks!

Comment: next time formulate your question better, this is way to general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 =If(e37='inclusive';sum(f3:f35)*1,36;sum(f3:f35))
```

assuming that g3 to g35 is the range of numbers to use in the calculation and taxes are 36% and the term inclusive should be exact what ia used in the select list of course

Comment: thanks daniel for helping but how can i pass this code to
dropdown box has two options inclusive and exlusive. i want it to do two thing if i select inclusive it show inclusive and show subtotal in total box..and if i select exlusice it show result.

Comment: Data -> Validation -> Select list and point to two cells that will contain only "Inclusive" and "Exclusive" that way no other choice will be accepted by Excel. Using Daniel's code it will work (though I'm a fan of using UPPER() or LOWER() to be sure no error is made due to case sensitivity). The only adjustment I'd make to Daniel's code is to make the tax rate in a specific cell so that if you change it in that cell you do not have to change the formula.

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur good suggestions both